# Objective C SQLite Not Recognized as a Database

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am attempting to create a process to backup my app data stored in a SQLite file. To this point I have been able to successfully hook into the Dropbox SDK, upload a backup file then download the backup file. I am stuck attempting to replace the current .sqlite with the downloaded backup .sqlite. Replacing the file itself did not yield desired results so I attempted to drop the tables of the current DB and re-load them from the backup. However when attempting to query the backup I am getting an error that the file is encrypted (it is not) or not a database. Error message = DB Open Error: file is encrypted or is not a database.
Code to simply count records from a table in backup below. If anyone has any ideas or even better a simpler way for me to swap out the existing .sqlite for the backup.sqlite that would be much appreciated.

```
self.dbManagerBackup = [[DBManager alloc] initWithDatabaseFilename:@"Backup.sqlite"];
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from Table1"];

if (self.Backup != nil) {
    self.Backup = nil;
}

self.Backup = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbManagerBackup loadDataFromDB:query]];

NSLog(@"*** Backup Backup Count = %lu",(unsigned long)self.Backup.count);
```

Comment: May be in file from dropbox you have somethinig like: 403/404 error instead of db file?

Comment: I would try to open the file with regular file operations to confirm that it is okay.

Comment: I was able to use the terminal to access the file as a database without issue.